# Number of reads with firestore stream

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I looked at the [documentation](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore) for the firestore plugin in Flutter and tried the code regarding the snapshots myself. It works fine, but I have the feeling, that whenever I change a single document within the collection, the entire list will be downloaded and the ListView will be printed again.

Now I am curious, if all the other, unaffected documents will really be downloaded all over again and thus count as document reads. When I run the same code in normal dart language, only the document that changes will get downloaded, so I consider switching to that approach and building the list myself.

Comment: did you get any information about this ?